# How could my code tell a compile-time constant versus a variable?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, macros, metaprogramming

Here's my problem. I have a `BINARY_FLAG` macro:

```
#define BINARY_FLAG( n ) ( static_cast<DWORD>( 1 << ( n ) ) )
```

Which can be used either like this ("constant" scenario):

```
static const SomeConstant = BINARY_FLAG( 5 );
```

or like this ("variable" scenario):

```
for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    DWORD flag = BINARY_FLAG( i );
    // do something with the value
}
```

This macro is not foolproof at all - one can pass `-1` or `34` there and there will at most be a warning yet behavior will be undefined. I'd like to make it more foolproof.

For the constant scenario I could use a template:

```
template<int Shift> class BinaryFlag {
staticAssert( 0 <= Shift && Shift < sizeof( DWORD) * CHAR_BIT );
public:
static const DWORD FlagValue = static_cast<DWORD>( 1 << Shift );
};
#define BINARY_FLAG( n ) CBinaryFlag<n>::FlagValue
```

but this will not go for the "variable" scenario - I'd need a runtime assertion there:

```
inline DWORD ProduceBinaryFlag( int shift )
{
    assert( 0 <= shift && shift < sizeof( DWORD) * CHAR_BIT );
    return static_cast<DWORD>( 1 << shift );
}
#define BINARY_FLAG( n ) ProduceBinaryFlag(n)
```

The latter is good, but has no compile-time checks. Of course, I'd like a compile-time check where possible and a runtime check otherwise. At all times I want as little runtime overhead as possible so I don't want a function call (that maybe won't be inlined) when a compile-time check is possible.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3299834/57428), but it doesn't look like it is about the same problem.

Is there some construct that would allow to alternate between the two depending on whether the expression passed as a flag number is a compile-time constant or a variable?

Comment: `assert( 0 <= flag && flag < 32 )`... did you mean `flag` ==means==> `shift` here ? Also, if you pass an arguement to `ProduceBinaryFlag()` at runtime, then how can you check at compile time ? Or am I missing anything ?

Comment: Another example: `const int myflag = 5; BINARY_FLAG(myflag);`. `myflag` is a compile-time constant, but not a literal. The example in the question only uses one special case of a compile-time constant.

Comment: A thought - if you're willing to assume a C++ implementation that supports VLAs, then the macro could first do a runtime check, then declare an array whose size is positive if `n` is in range and negative otherwise. In the case where `n` is an integer constant expression, this will fail at compile-time provided that the expression denoting the size is also an ICE. In the case where `n` is not constant, UB will be prevented by the runtime check. Since the array is small and unused, hopefully it won't have significant cost.

Comment: @iammilind: I fixed the code. Well, yes, if I pass it into a  function it's not a compile time check anymore and that is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Did you try actually looking at the generated assembly? I would expect the function to not only be inlined 100% of the time, but to be subsequently optimized into the result of the calculation where possible (i.e. because the parameter is known at runtime). At worst there would be a spurious call to `assert(false)`. But what's wrong with just expecting the caller to use the template version with compile-time constants and the parameterized version with runtime values?

Comment: In the current state of C++0x implementations, this is not cleanly possible. When compilers implement `constexpr`, you'll have a way. In the meantime, I don't see why your macro isn't OK.

Comment: @Alexandre C.: Which one macro implementation do you mean?

Comment: @sharptooth: the first one. Selecting an expression based on its `constexpr`ness doesn't seem possible to me given current implementations of C++0x standard (and completely impossible with C++03 compilers).

Comment: I can try one construct for `BINARY_FLAG(n)` where `n` can only be numbers. If it's some named variable or constant then it will throw error. But that's what you want ? I mean do you want that `BINARY_FLAG()` should be passed only number literals and nothing else.

Comment: @iammilind: No, I want it to be passed anything and behave differently depending on whether it is a compile-time known constant of any kind or a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **not possible** to pass an argument to a macro or function and determine if it's compile time constant or a variable.

The best way is that you `#define BINARY_FLAG(n)` with compile time code and place that macro everywhere and then compile it. You will receive compiler-errors at the places where `n` is going to be runtime. Now, you can replace those macros with your runtime macro `BINARY_FLAG_RUNTIME(n)`. This is the only feasible way.

Answer (score 2):

This is simpler than you think :)

Let's have a look:

```
#include <cassert>

static inline int FLAG(int n) {
    assert(n>=0 && n<32);
    return 1<<n;
}

int test1(int n) {
    return FLAG(n);
}
int test2() {
    return FLAG(5);
}
```

I don't use MSVC, but I compiled with Mingw GCC 4.5:

> g++ -c -S -O3 08042.cpp

The resulting code for first method looks like:

```
__Z5test1i:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $24, %esp
    movl    8(%ebp), %ecx
    cmpl    $31, %ecx
    ja  L4
    movl    $1, %eax
    sall    %cl, %eax
    leave
    ret
L4:
    movl    $4, 8(%esp)
    movl    $LC0, 4(%esp)
    movl    $LC1, (%esp)
    call    __assert
    .p2align 2,,3
```

And the second:

```
__Z5test2v:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl    $32, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

See? The compiler is smart enough to do it for you. No need for macros, no need for metaprogramming, no need for C++0x. As simple as that.

Check if MSVC does the same... But look - **it's really easy for the compiler to evaluate a constant expression and drop the unused conditional branch.** Check it if you want to be sure... But generally - trust your tools.

Comment: This is just great except I won't get a compile-time error for surely illegal usecases. Runtime error will only occur on some dataset and a compile-time error would occur immediately upon compilation.

Comment: True. How is that static assert implemented? With the above, all we need is a static assertion which would compile silently into nothing if its parameter cannot be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: Which *might* be impossible since a template parameter can be either a typename or a constant expression... Hm. This needs Trickery!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use two macros. 
**BINARY_FLAG
CONST_BINARY_FLAG**
That will make your code easier to grasp for others. You do know, at the time of writing, if it is a const or not. 
And I would in no case worry about runtime overhead. Your optimizer, at least in VS, **will** sort that out for you.