# Can I overload an implicit initialization to 0?

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer, explicit-constructor

Is it possible to write a class such that these are valid:

```
Foo a;
Foo b = 0;
Foo c = b;
Foo d(0);
Foo e(1);
Foo f = Foo(1);
```

But these are not:

```
int x;
Foo a = x;
Foo b = 1;
Foo c = 2;
//etc
```

Essentially, my rule is *"A constant `0` is implicitly convertible to a `Foo`,  but no other value is"*

Comment: What about `Foo e(1);`? How is that valid?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Are they semantically identical? If so, I guess I can declare that invalid.

Comment: Maybe you can try with a constructor taking a `std::nullptr_t` (just an idea...)

Comment: What if `x` was `const int x = 0;`, would you want `a`'s initialization to succeed?

Comment: Perhaps this could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299834/c-compile-time-constant-detection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658060/how-can-i-elide-a-call-if-an-edge-condition-is-known-at-compile-time?lq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind `Foo b = nullptr;` working, it's pretty easy to hack up. Have an explicit constructor from `int`, and an implicit from `std::nullptr_t`.

If you do mind that working, I'm not sure it's possible. The only way to distinguish between a literal `0` and other integer literals is the former's implicit conversion to pointers and `nullptr_t`. So `nullptr` will prefer a `nullptr_t` parameter to a pointer parameter, so by having both constructors you could filter out `nullptr` arguments. However, the conversions of `0` to pointers and `nullptr_t` are of the same rank, so this would kill `0` arguments with an ambiguity.

Hmm ... something like this may work:

```
class Foo {
  struct dummy;
public:
  explicit Foo(int); // the version that allows Foo x(1);
  Foo(dummy*); // the version that allows Foo x = 0;
  template <typename T,
            typename = typename std::enable_if<
                std::is_same<T, std::nullptr_t>::value>::type>
  Foo(T) = delete; // the version that prevents Foo x = nullptr;
};
```

I haven't actually tried this. In theory, the template should only participate in overload resolution when the argument is `nullptr`, because otherwise SFINAE kills it. In that case, however, it should be better than the pointer constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
Foo e(1);
```

Will call a non-explicit constructor of Foo taking an int as argument.
Essentially this line will do the same by trying to convert int to Foo using this int constructor.

```
Foo b = 1;
```

You can't prevent certain values of that int to be processed directly.
If you have your constructor `explicit` you won't be able to write the next line, too.

```
Foo b = 0;
```

gx_ stated correctly that 0 can be converted to std::nullptr_t.
The following will work with respect to your intent.

```
Foo(std::nullptr_t x) : member(0) { }
explicit Foo(int c) : member(c) { }
// ...
Foo a = 0; // compiles
Foo b = 1; // doesn't compile

// Note:
int do_stuff (void) { return 0; }
Foo c = do_stuff(); // doesn't compile
```

Comment: Nope, direct- vs. copy- initialization.

Comment: How about an `explicit Foo(int);` plus a `Foo(nullptr_t);`?

Answer (score -1):

One idea I had was:

```
Foo(const uint32_t c) : member(0) { static_assert(c == 0, "Nope"); }
explicit Foo(uint32_t c) : member(c) { }
```

Does this behave sensibly?

Comment: That won't even compile. As far as overload resolution is concerned, a `const uint32_t` parameter and a `uint32_t` parameter are the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

I admit I haven't achieved complete mastery of the rvalue semantics of C++11 yet, but this seems to do what you want:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
    Foo(int&&) {}
};

int main()
{
    Foo a(123);
    int x = 123;
    Foo b(x); // error here, line 11
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

> prog.cpp:11: error: cannot bind ‘int’ lvalue to ‘int&&’

Comments welcome, if this code has any caveats I haven't noticed, or if you can reassure me that it doesn't.

Comment: Interesting, but I'm aiming for the specific case of `x == 0`;

Comment: @eric Ah, didn't realise that. You said `Foo e(1);` should be valid :/